# How to intercept the SOAP Request/Response Made from Salesforce or received in Salesforce?

Tags: xml, soap, apex, callout

I am working a salesforce integration project. We are making n number of web service calls to third party services. Now I have to implement a logger , where I need to store the soap request and response in xml format. Most preferable is the same soap request and response xml.

How I can intercept this request and response , in apex programmatically ?

Is it the only option left to xml serialize my request and response explicitly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every body for participating . I did intercepted in the proxy class (Generated from WSDL) and logged the toString() response (I have overridden the request and response stubs for as Json) of request and response objects into a custom sObject.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is made from Salesforce, the XML should be visible in the log when **CALLOUT** LogLevel is set: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_API_calls.htm

Another solution is to use a proxy server that stores the data outside Salesforce.

Comment: That doesn't actually give you the raw request